# Searchbar getting Text but not filtering List

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

As stated in the title, I have a Listview which I want to filter. I looked up endless examples and code snippets, but I still don't get where I have to put

```
list = list.where((u)=>(u.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())
            .toList()));
```

to get the list filtered.

I assume that I have to change something in the way I build the list.
The Textfield already works fine, `_searchText` is always what the Textfield says.

My code:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ac/collectible/collectible_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ac/nooklets/nook_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ac/nooklets/nook_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ac/nooklets/nook_sheet.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ac/settings.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'collectible.dart';

final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();

class CollectibleList<C extends Collectible> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<C> collectibles;
  final String title;
  

  CollectibleList(
    this.collectibles,
    {
      this.title,
    }

  );

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CollectibleList<C>();
}

class _CollectibleList<C extends Collectible> extends State<CollectibleList<C>> {
  Widget _appBarTitle;
  bool _isSearching;
  String _searchText = "";
  List _collectibles = new List(); 
  List _filteredCollectibles = new List(); 
  Icon _searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.search); 
  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var list;

  _CollectibleList(){
      _filter.addListener(() {

      if (_filter.text.isEmpty) {

        setState(() {

          _searchText = "";
          _isSearching = false;
         list = list.where((u)=>(u.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())
            .toList()));

        });

      } else {

        setState(() {

          _searchText = _filter.text;

          log(_searchText);

        });

      }

    });
  }
  void _openDetails(Collectible collectible) {
    var locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

    log("Opening collectible details for ${collectible.name(locale)}");

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CollectibleDetails(collectible)),
    );
    
  }

  @protected
  @override
  void initState() {
    _appBarTitle = new Text(widget.title ?? "");
    super.initState();
      _isSearching = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    var collectibles = widget.collectibles ?? [];

    var list = ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        height: 1,
        thickness: 1,
      ),
      itemCount: collectibles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Collectible collectible = collectibles[index];

        return Consumer<Settings>(
          builder: (context, settings, child) {
            var titleStyle = !collectible.isObtained(settings) ?
              null :
              TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              );

            return Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Hero(
                  tag: collectible.heroTag,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image(image: collectible.icon),
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text("${collectible.name(locale)}", style: titleStyle),
                subtitle: collectible.listSubtitle(context),
                trailing: collectible.listTrailing(context),
                onTap: () => _openDetails(collectible),
                onLongPress: () {
                  var isObtained = collectible.isObtained(settings);
                  collectible.setObtained(settings, !isObtained);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: _appBarTitle,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(95, 199, 188, 1.0),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: _searchIcon,
            onPressed: () {
              log("Searchbutton pressed");
              _searchPressed();
              //showSearch(context: context, delegate: Datasearch());
              }
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list)
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: NookScaffold(
        body: NookSheet(
            child: 
              Column(children:<Widget>[
                DropdownButton(onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    String dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });       
                }
                ),
                
                Expanded(child: list)
              ],),
          ),
        titleMargin: 0,
      )
    );
  }


  void _searchPressed() {
    setState(() 
      {
        if (this._searchIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
          this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
          this._appBarTitle = new TextField(
            controller: _filter,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search),
              hintText: 'Search...',
            ),
            
          );
          _handleSearchStart();
        } else {
          this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
          this._appBarTitle = new Text(widget.title ?? "");
          _filteredCollectibles = _collectibles;
          _filter.clear();
        }
      }
    );
  }

    void _handleSearchStart(ListView list) {
    setState(() {
      _isSearching = true;
    });
  }
  List<ChildItem> _buildList() {
    return list.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact)).toList();
  }

  List<ChildItem> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return list.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact))
          .toList();
    }
    else {
      List<String> _searchList = List();
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        String  name = list.elementAt(i);
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
          _searchList.add(name);
        }
      }
      return _searchList.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact))
          .toList();
    }
  }


  }

  class ChildItem extends StatelessWidget {
    final String name;
    ChildItem(this.name);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new ListTile(title: new Text(this.name));
    }

  
}
```

Comment: You are populating the list view every time with your widget's collectible. `var collectibles = widget.collectibles ?? [];`. 
Assign the widget.collectible to some state variable and filter that variable. And provide that variable to the listview.

Comment: If I write ```filteredCollectibles = collectibles.where((u)=>(u.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())
            .toList()));``` then I get an error:The method 'toLowerCase' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toLowerCase'.dart(undefined_method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to implement the "Search as you type" feature for your text field.

There are two ways (probably more) to get this working.

## 1. Manual way:

You can use streams to listen for what the user has typed in, and based on what data comes in, you filter the data which you are feeding to your list items.

Better explanation: As the user types, for each and every character that he/she hits, you send data into your stream and from the other side, you keep listening to what is being fed to the stream. User types "A" you feed "A" to your stream and get the same from other side, and filter everything that starts/ends(Or whatever your needs are...) with "A". This goes for each and every character that the user types in.

Code Sample: (Assuming your UI and data functions are in different files)

This is how your BLOC class might look like, it has a StreamController whose job is just to listen to data and pass it to the place you need.

```
class Bloc{
  final _textFieldController = StreamController<String>();

  //Use this to get data out of the stream
  Stream<String> get enteredCharacter => _textFieldController.stream;

  //returns functions to change data
  Function(String) get addText => _textFieldController.sink.add;

  dispose() {
    _textFieldController.close();
  }
}
//Here we are using a single instance of the bloc class, Which you can access from anywhere.
final bloc = Bloc();
```

Now, How to use it?

In the file where your data functions reside, more importantly where the data that is being fed to the listview lives, You need to listen to the stream for what's coming in as follows:

```
var enteredCharacter = "";
bloc.enteredCharacter.listen((data) {
  print("This is the character entered by the user: $data");
  enteredCharacter = data;
  _filterData(); //This function will filter your data based on the characters that the user hits.
});
```

## Easy or Pre-Built way:

Use a plugin called `autocomplete_textfield`, It's easy to use and pretty much does the job.

[Click here for plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield)

Comment: Your easy pre-build way description made me laugh. I will try to use both and keep using whatever fits better

Comment: I understand what you are writing but I can't find the exact location where I would have to put your code since you seem to use some other declarations. I create the data for the Listview at ``` var collectibles = widget.collectibles ?? []; ``` but I don't know how I have to change that. I am still a total newbie in dart

Comment: I already get the text I need to filter the list with. But I am unable to actually get the part right that filters the list

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that the stream is returning the data (Characters that the user types in)?

Comment: print("This is the character entered by the user: $data"); is this being printed to the console?

Comment: No. My method ```_searchPressed``` is displaying the text in the console log. I have to Idea where to place your stream in my code. I would know in java but not in dart yet.

Comment: Also, "_filterList" from your codesample is not defined and throws an error